# Spring Webflux - Publish all HTTP requests to pubsub

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

In my app I have one endpoint under `/my-endpoint` path which supports only post method. It accepts a body that must be compatible with my `MyRequest` class.

```
@Validated
data class MyRequest(
    @get:JsonProperty("age", required = true)
    @field:Size(min = 3, max = 128, message = "age must be between 3 and 128")
    val age: String,

    @get:JsonProperty("zip_code", required = true)
    @field:Pattern(regexp = "\\d{2}-\\d{3}", message = "address.zip_code is invalid. It is expected to match pattern \"\\d{2}-\\d{3}\"")
    val zipCode: String
)
```

And my controller looks like this

```
@PostMapping("/my-endpoint")
fun myEndpoint(
    @Valid @RequestBody request: MyRequest,
): Mono<ResponseEntity<MyResponse>> {
    return myService.processRequest(request)
    .map { ResponseEntity.ok().body(it) }
}
```

Each time I receive some request to THIS particular endpoint (I have other endpoints but them should be ignored) - I'd like to publish a message to my pubsub consisting raw request body (as a string) - no matter whether the request body was valid or not.

How to intercept the request to be able to publish the message - still having the endpoint working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could implement your own [WebFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/WebFilter.html#filter-org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange-org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain-). Filter the API path through `exchange.getRequest().getPath()` using simple if block and get the body through `exchange.getRequest().getBody()`

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class MyFilter implements WebFilter {

  private final MyPublisher myPublisher;

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    if (pathMatches(exchange.getRequest().getPath()) {
      return exchange.getRequest().getBody()
          .map(dataBuffer -> {
            final String requestBody = dataBuffer.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            this.myPublisher.publish(requestBody).subscribe();
            return exchange;
          }).then(chain.filter(exchange));
    }
    return chain.filter(exchange);
  }
}
```